# How To Extract a Month From a String Date?

Tags: powerbuilder

I have a tab delimited text that i'm extracting it's data but i found a challenge with converting some dates because they are in a different format like this one `1 AUG 1989` i'm taking the data as a string and i'm looping through it to decompose it and build a valid date with it 
Here is my code for the date separated with a Space(" ") Thanks for your help

```
//Extract the day 
ll_strtsearch = 1 
ll_fsearch = Pos(ls_tmp ," " , ll_strtsearch)
ll_len = ll_fsearch - ll_strtsearch 
ls_tmpdate = Trim(Mid(ls_tmp , ll_strtsearch , ll_len )) 
ll_day = Long(ls_tmpdate)

//Extract the Month
ll_strtsearch = ll_fsearch + 1 
ll_fsearch = Pos(ls_tmp , " " , ll_strtsearch)
ll_len = ll_fsearch - ll_strtsearch
ls_tmpdate = Trim(Mid(ls_tmp , ll_strtsearch , ll_len)) 
ll_month = Month(ld_tmp)
//ll_month = Long(ls_tmpdate) 


//Extract the Year 
ll_strtsearch = ll_fsearch + 1 
ll_len = 4
setNull(ld_empDob)
ls_tmpdate = Trim(Mid(ls_tmp , ll_strtsearch , ll_len)) 
if len(ls_tmpdate) = 4 Then
    ll_year = Long(ls_tmpdate)
Else 
    If len(ls_tmpdate) = 2 Then 
        ls_tmpdate = "19" + ls_tmpdate 
        ld_empDob = Date(Long(ls_tmp) , 1 ,1 )
    End If
```

Comment: the `Month()` function can only work on a date type. Are the data localised in different languages? If not, you can make a text array containing the 12 months names as a simple lookup table. It depends on the quantity of data to process.

Comment: I know about the month () function and i thought about the array idea but i just thought that maybe there is a better way to it

Comment: Have you tried just using the Date(<string>) method?  This way you would only have to deal with exceptions.  Formats can differ depending upon the Windows settings on the machine the executable is running on.

Comment: Yes i did try it but with no results it returned 1900-1-1

Comment: When you said no results, you mean null results? or something similar?, because your easily can use Date("yourdate"), and then part the date in Day, Month, Year, etc. check my post and answer my question to improve it.

Comment: i have tried this method Date(ld_tempdate) to check for the date before entering this piece of code but it returned 1900-1-1 thus i have entered it in this code because the dates i have in the text are with a different formats some are missing the day and month and some are space separated and some other space separated and finally this format 1 AUG 1989

Comment: One suggestion, try to uniform your format, if you can't do it that, put in your post all the possible formats to improve the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the current format provided you can use this:

```
long ll_day,ll_month,ll_year

ls_tmp = '1 AUG 1989' // d mmm yyyy 
ll_day = Day(date(ls_tmp))
ll_month = Month(date(ls_tmp))
ll_year = Year(date(ls_tmp))
```

and If you want continue using your code, change this in the month case:

```
//Extract the Month
ll_strtsearch = ll_fsearch + 1 
ll_fsearch = Pos(ls_tmp , " " , ll_strtsearch)
ll_len = ll_fsearch - ll_strtsearch
ls_tmpdate = Trim(Mid(ls_tmp , ll_strtsearch , ll_len)) 
ll_month = Month(date(ls_tmp))
//ll_month = Long(ls_tmpdate)
```

If you need help about other formats you need to provide it them.

Comment: Actually i was having troubles only with this format the rest is too easy thx for your help

Comment: If this answer helped you I would appreciate that you mark the question as solved, if you need more help just edit your post to continue :).